# Deleting files from folder encrypted with fscrypt

Tags: linux, file-encryption, deletion

I have a folder encrypted with fscrypt. If I unlock this folder and delete a file from it (as the folder is unlocked anyone can see the contents of the files), then after deletion I lock this folder again, what will happen to this deleted file? Can it be recovered by forensic means? Will they be able to read the file's content?

I've searched online but couldn't find anything about deleting files from fscrypt encrypted folders. I'm on ubuntu.